# Detecting whether a div is visible or not using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to determine the visibility of a specific `<div>`, but my check always shows it as being visible. I am using the following code:

```
if($('.stg_gall_cro_cnt').is(":visible")) {
    var visi="yes";
} 
else {
    var visi="no";
}
alert(visi);
```

Every time this check runs, the alert says "yes", even if the `<div>` is not visible. Can someone help?

The css for the `.stg_gall_cro_cnt` is set by default to:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('.stg_gall_cro_cnt').css('visibility') === 'hidden'){
    // hidden
}else{
    // visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector only matches elements that occupy no space in the rendered document. Elements whose `visibility` is set to `hidden` occupy space so jQuery considers them visible.

You need to set `display: none` in CSS to achieve the desired effect using `is(':visible')` or use `css('visibility') == 'hidden'` in jQuery to accomplish it with `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @SakshiSharma wanovak's answer shows how to test if an element occupies space but is invisible.